# Dynamic drop-down based on Index & Match variable

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a relatively simple search (no index keys possible) for a license plate in a log using cell A15. To the right cells, B15 and C15 auto-populate perfectly using index and match functions.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eKIF3aeY-yUlG9RpRxP8YWYm9Vj78SYWut3B9GGNOhU/edit?usp=sharing

There are only a couple of problems. First, there are times when a different driver might be driving the same vehicle, so a drop down to choose the relative row would be good. Note that at least 3 people are driving Frank's truck, yet the only reference we have for search criteria is the license plate.

Huge bonus if someone could explain how I can use the same cells (A15, B15 & C16) with multiple Index & Match functions so that either the license plate OR the name could be used as the criteria to autofill fill the other data.

`=index(B2:B12,MATCH(A15,A2:A12,0))`

Comment: Is a nested index and match an option for the last paragraph? I don't even know if such a nested formula is a real thing. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**B15:**

```
=QUERY({A2:C13}, "select Col2,Col3 where Col1='"&A15&"'", 0)
```

**B24:**

```
=QUERY({A2:C13}, "select Col1,Col3 where Col2='"&A24&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

to get unique values only use `UNIQUE`:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({A2:C13}, "select Col1,Col3 where Col2='"&A24&"'", 0))
```

Comment: Seriously you are a god! This is exactly what I have been trying to learn today PLUS SOME! Also the second time you helped me player0, if we hit a third I'm hitting that  paypal link bro!

I really appreciate you putting the code within the answer, I can use it to learn and experiment with. Completely off topic have you ever linked Sheets to Datatable.net projects? I think it is done with JSON.

Comment: nope, no experience with Datatable.net at all, sry.

Comment: Not asking for any more help on this, just a question... Is it beyond the capabilities of Sheets to merge the two examples of code into the same row? In this way it could pull the dynamic data for 2 columns.

Comment: should be doable. the question is at what level of scope you wish to have it. I can think of several... can you show me some example of what desired output you wish for?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14K6c_ot4fYMgDdgO8Q70jLe3b0F1MeaO7VyWkCyQ2Z4/edit?usp=sharing
I am trying to save a transcription team a ton of data entry time for vehicles that enter a property on a regular basis basically. Granted they can't use auto fill every time but any time savings I am sure they would appreciate. I am just trying to help them.

Comment: Is it a violation of rules to exchange contact information? I would like to know what your rates are and availability if it is ok to extend the discussion beyond Stack Overflow.